# Distribution of charge in uniform hollow sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

In electrostatics we learn that if we put excess charge in a hollow sphere, the charges eventually get distributed on the surface uniformly. But there is one thing I don't understand: hollow sphere means the space inside the sphere is void, meaning there is nothing inside. So how can a charge be even kept in that void? Does this charge mean a charged body (*also how can we even place a charged body in the sphere when it is closed*)? Even if it were, how can a charge body even fly through that void and reach the surface? Also we are taught that electrons flow in wires, but again I have the same question in mind. There are atoms on the surface of the wire but inside the wire, it is the same void or nothingness. So how can electrons even travel through that space?

I know the questions I am asking are naïve and they might not even make sense but even after being able to solve mathematical problems related to electrostatics, I seem to not have the proper understanding of the basics. Hopefully, someone will shed light on this.

Comment: *how can a charge body even fly through that void* Is it different from an airplane flying through the air, or a rocket shop flying through outer space, or you jumping off a diving board into a swimming pool? Objects can move through space.

Comment: "*Hollow sphere means the space inside the sphere is void meaning there is nothing inside. So how can a charge be even kept in that void?*" True but pedagogically this is no different than imagining an ideal "battery" to supply a constant voltage without regards to current, or a piece of mass lifted in a gravitational field while assuming that the field is not effected by the motion of that mass, etc. These are idealizations to get you accustomed to electrostatic behavior of fields and its sources. You cannot start EM theory *and* practice with the operation of the rail gun.